# Upgrading jQuery Library form 1.7.1 to 1.10.1 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have developed a web application by using jQuery 1.7.1. Now I am trying to switch to jQuery 1.10.2 but it isn't working.

Upon using the latest version, none of my existing jQuery code works.

I am using the Google-hosted version of jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is it OK to stay with 1.7.1? How can I upgrade to 1.10.2?

I am getting the following messages in my browser's console:

> Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.
>
> The Web Console logging API (console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error) has been disabled by a script on this page.

Comment: in version 1.9 there were a few breaking changes like removing support for `live` and so on to see full list of changes see http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9

Comment: "It is not working" is the most meaningless error message ever quoted. What "isn't working"? How isn't it working? What error messages do you see in your console? Which line in your code is incompatible? There is absolutely no way we can diagnose that without any information.

Comment: the first thing to do is to check the browser's console to see the errors... and you can use the migration plugin to add support for removed featurs https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: Thanks @Arun P Johny for quick replay, Is it okay to stay with 1.7.1 ?

Comment: I would recommend upgrading with migration plugin

Comment: @Teemu The browser auto-resolves that, so it's recommended to omit it so that it can be transferred over the same protocol as the rest of your content

Comment: @Teemu ...because in a local file the browser auto-resolves to the "file://" protocol, but this resource apparently isn't on your local machine `:)`. Try it on a webpage, or just have a look at the google cdn page.

Comment: @Teemu There is no issue of loading

Comment: @BOSS Which browser are you using? If there are no errors in your console why do you think there's something wrong? What's supposed to happen (*show code*), and what is actually happening?

Comment: @nbrooks Using firefox, As I described am not get any response from jquery events, Like ajax calls, dropdown, mouseover etc

Comment: @BOSS Even one specific example is better than none. If you have a document ready handler, or main function, post that in your question. It looks like you're not seeing errors because you're console is disabled. Try commenting out the non-jQuery scripts and seeing if you can get error messages to appear. (Or try viewing in Firebug/a different browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jquery-migrate: Migrate older jQuery code to jQuery 1.9+](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

Migrate is a best solution I found

Thanks – [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) for your helping comment